# Console not scrolling up, and no wake from console blanking

Tags: console

Fresh install of Debian 11.1 using the Debian Live CD (to benefit non-free Wi-Fi drivers), on Dell Latitude E6430.

Under X, everything works fine.

In console, I have two issues that may be related (or not?):

- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>PageUp</kbd> does not scroll console up
- after the monitor goes off (after about 5 minutes, default settings), pressing keys or moving the touchpad does not wake the monitor; only switching to the X console wakes the monitor (if I had launched X previously; I have never had the case of letting the monitor go off without X running on the side).

Any ideas?

Comment: I am not familiar with the details behind the scenes but in `screen` I need the setting `termcapinfo xterm ti@:te@` for Shift PageUp to work. Maybe that is helpful somehow.

Comment: Linus removed console scroll back a few months ago. He says he didn't think anyone used it.